my react-native typescript android app is crashing when i will redirect to screen in which i have used react-native-qrcode-scanner

react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5"
"react-native-camera": "^4.2.1"
"react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5"
"react": "18.2.0"
"react-native": "0.74.3"

app is crash without any error log
I have tried uninstall package and reinstall again, but it didn't work
any help will really appreciated....
thanks in advance

Can you run it with logcat from android studio up? That should tell you exactly what crashed it on the native side.

yes I did run with android studio. and error logcat is throw an error related to react-native-camera
Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.hal1.packagelist"
FATAL EXCEPTION: RNCamera-Handler-Thread
